# Fusion Chart - line chart

Tags: fusioncharts, linechart

How we can draw a line chart using fusionchart.rendercharthtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create the chart with the following code

```
FusionCharts.RenderChart("/Charts/FCF_Line.swf", "", strXML, "ResourceVsCO1", "400", "200", false, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can refer the link-
http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/

Not only the Line chart there is a complete documentation support in the above link.
hope this helps!!